# Can we say Polkadot is a sidechain of Ethereum

Tags: polkadot

There is something i do not understand about Polkadot.

Can we say Polkadot is a sidechain of Ethereum ? Or is it contestant of Ethereum ?

Is it correct to say "Polkadot is not a Layer 2 of Ethereum but a Layer 1 sidechain" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PolkaDot Brings Multiple Blockchains into One Network by Unlocking Scalability and Extensibility

Polkadot is not a sidechain of Ethereum. Polkadot is basically an ecosystem for cross-chain communication. It has parachains like sidechains in Ethereum but in Polkadot, the main chain is a relay chain.

Moreover, In the parachain the ethereum chain can also be included as well as many other blockchains.